# NumPy - Unpacking data with different dtypes from a file using genfromtxt

Tags: string, csv, numpy, io

I am trying to read in a file where the 1st column is a date string and columns 2-4 are regular floating point numbers. If I do

```
data = np.genfromtxt("infile.csv", delimiter=','),
```

I get an array of 4x rows in file where all the values in column 1 are (quite rightly) NaNs. So to get my date as a string I tried

```
data = np.genfromtxt("infile.csv", delimiter=',', dtype=("|S20",float,float,float))
```

Outcome is a 1D array with all four columns of each row now as one element of the array.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: You are instructing genfromtxt to return an array of 4-element tuples. Take a look at the `converters` input option to `np.genfromtxt`. If you create a converter that returns the date as a float, you don't need to specify dtype (it will default to float). If you want your date as a different dtype (e.g. datetime), you can specify dtype=None (to create an object array).

Comment: If you provide a few lines of the file you're trying to import we can help you define your converter.

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways to do this, but since we don't know how you plan to handle the date string a quick (to write, not to run depending on the amount of data) and dirty way would be to use some loops:

```
data_tup = tuple(np.empty(len(data), dtype=data.dtype[i]) for i in range(len(data[0])))
for i, line in enumerate(data):
    for j, item in enumerate(line):
        data_tup[j][i] = item
```

This will give you a tuple of ndarrays with data from each column.